# flutter Firebase Facebook login internal error on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, flutter

I'm trying to implement Firebase Facebook login but it throws an error says like so.

> PlatformException(sign_in_failed, FIRAuthErrorDomain, An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.)

I enabled Facebook method and paste code in plist.
What am I doing wrong?
Anyone have an idea?

**Code**

```
try {
  final FacebookLogin facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
  final result = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);
  switch (result.status) {
    case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn: 
      final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithFacebook(accessToken: result.accessToken.token);
      print(user.uid);
    break;
    case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
      print('ERROR');
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
 } catch (e) {
    print(e);
}
```

Comment: have you a google login as well?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yeah I did.

Comment: what did you do?

Comment: I ended up not using facebook login but I'm sure this issue has something to with google login.

Comment: yeah if the facebook account had the same gmail account as the google sign ...there was problems

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Is there any workaround?